# About combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 5 Americans, 4 Mexicans, 3 Argentines and 2 Uruguayans. If I want to form a committee of 5 people, with the condition that each nationality is represented I know that I have to calculate the following way:
$$
[{5 \choose 2} \times {4 \choose 1} \times {3 \choose 1} \times {2 \choose 1}] + \\ [{5 \choose 1} \times {4 \choose 2} \times {3 \choose 1} \times {2 \choose 1}] + \\ [{5 \choose 1} \times {4 \choose 1} \times {3 \choose 2} \times {2 \choose 1}]+ \\ [{5 \choose 1} \times {4 \choose 1} \times {3 \choose 1} \times {2 \choose 2}] \ \ \ \ 
$$
But I want to know, why doesn't work this way: 
$$
[{5 \choose 1} \times {4 \choose 1} \times {3 \choose 1} \times {2 \choose 1} \times {10 \choose 1}]
$$
I mean, I know I'm duplicating the favorable cases, but why? Why do I have to divide by 2? What's the intuition?

Comment: Can you explain your notation? What is "$c1$", eg? What is the last term in your preferred version (the $10c1$)? There is no group w/ 10 people.

Comment: By 5c2 i mean: \frac {5!}{ (1!) \times (5-1)!} also, all groups of 1 person that you can make with 5 different persons. 10c1 means that, with the last 10 persons y can choose just one of them.

Comment: For the record, even though I think I know, you should explicitly state in your question what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: So was that supposed to be *5 choose 2* (${5 \choose 2}$ `{5 \choose 2}`)?

Comment: that's right! i just edit them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning correct. You first pick exactly one person from each group which is just $5c1\times 4c1\times 3c1\times 2c1$. This leaves $5+4+3+2-4=10$ people,any of which is fine. You're double counting because the resulting value does not take into account switching one of the first 4 picked people and the 5'th person. For example, for the first 4 people you pick one from each nationality, say:

$\{Sam,Jose,Diego,Pablo\}$,

with nationalities

$\{American,Mexican,Argentinean,Uruguayan\}$,

respectively. For the last person you pick from any of the remaining people. If you pick Jack (an American) as the last person, you're double counting these two combinations:

$\{Sam,Jose,Diego,Pablo,Jack\}$,
$\{Jack,Jose,Diego,Pablo,Sam\}$

Comment: i think i got the argument, but why do you say that this would not occur if one of the nationalities had only 1 guy? does that means that if i had just one guy from Uruguay i could make the account like this? $[{5 \choose 1} \times {4 \choose 1} \times {3 \choose 1} \times {1 \choose 1} \times {9 \choose 1}] $

Comment: @CamiloAbbate: Ah, you're right!